# SQL connection gets implicitly closed on thread abort

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm opening SQL connection then running many SQL scripts in it. My program doesn't close connection at any spot but if I call Thread.Abort() then the connection sometimes gets closed (50/50).

The code looks like:

```
connection.Open();
try
{
  // running various SQL script, no one is closing connection
  // calling Thread.Abort() at this point
}
catch (ThreadAbortException ex)
{
  Thread.ResetAbort();
  // connection sometimes has state "Closed" here!!!
  new SqlCommand("blahblah", connection).ExecuteNonQuery(); // doesn't work then
}
```

Why it's happening? What should I do to have it alive until I explicitly close it?
This is call stack when connection is closed:

```
   at SNIReadSyncOverAsync(SNI_ConnWrapper* , SNI_Packet** , Int32 )
   at SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIReadSyncOverAsync(SafeHandle pConn, IntPtr& packet, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByte(Byte& value)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
```

Comment: @T.S. This all script runs under the same thread. Connection is being creting in it too. Also look, I'm calling Thread.ResetAbort().

Comment: Trying to abort a thread is a no no, why do you want to do such shenanigans

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cec647a0-a831-4761-8022-3759920ed498/sqltransaction-and-sqlconnection-state-after-worker-thread-aborted?forum=adodotnetdataproviders

Comment: in the wise words of the CLR wizard EricLippert "*In short, Thread.Abort is at best indicative of bad design, possibly unreliable, and extremely dangerous. It should be avoided at all costs; the only time you should ever even consider aborting a thread is in some sort of "emergency shutdown" code where you are attempting to tear down an appdomain as cleanly as possible*"

Comment: Also im upvoting because of your name

Comment: Is connection variable live on the same thread?

Comment: @EmrahSüngü sure

Comment: @linq2vodka do you have any finally blocks in the aborted thread

Comment: Please never call `Thread.Abort()`. Even if you handle any exceptions it can still corrupt the run-time meaning that the remaining threads may not function correctly. It should only be used when forcing an application to close.